# How toString() of AbstractCollection prints a Collection within Collection in Java?

Tags: java, collections

```java
List subitemsCategory=new ArrayList(); //Creating the subList
subitemsCategory.add("Garnier");       //Adding sublist
subitemsCategory.add("Bajaj");
List items=new ArrayList();            //Creating Main List
items.add("Shampoo");
items.add("Oil");
items.add(subitemsCategory);           //Adding a new List in items
System.out.println(items);             //Print Collection within Collection
```

How is a Collection within a Collection printed?

Comment: Type parameters.  You should use them.  (That might help you to understand your problem as well.)

Comment: Look at the source code: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#l453. It calls `append(e)`, where `e` is an element of the list, so it basically uses `e.toString()`.

Comment: sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);                                          //What Is the Purpose of ("this Collection") here?

Comment: `"this Collection"` is appended to the StringBuilder, meaning that the collection contains a reference to itself

Answer (score 1):

Through `toString` recursive calls.
In Java `toString` method can be invoked on every object, regardless of whether it is a list or not.

A list consisting of 3 strings `"a"`, `"b"` and `"c"` is printed this way:
`[a, b, c]`.
`[` is printed before elements,
then a comma-separated list is printed
and there is a `]` at the end.

What happens, when an element itself is a list?
Its `toString` method is executed, thus:
`[a, b, [c, d, e]]`

In your case:

```
[Shampoo, Oil, [Garnier, Bajaj]]
```

Following OP's another question...
What happens when we do:

```
Collection aCollection = //constructor call
aCollection.add(aCollection);
```

There are no errors like stack overflow etc.
It will simply print:

```
[..., (this Collection), ...]
```

which is the purpose of ternary operator usage [in the source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#l462).

Comment: sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e); //What Is Role Of "this Collection" here?

Comment: @SunnyAgrawal, If you do: `items.add(items)` in your code, you will see ;) It avoids infinite reference to the same collection.